# Slide out menu wont center div in the middle of the page when open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Question Background:**

I'm using an 'off the shelf' jQuery slide out panel menu within my app.

**The Issue**

The following screen shot shows the app with the slide menu closed. Note that the text is in a `div` centered in the middle of the page:

[image]

When the menu is opened the positioning is lost and the text is shown at the top of the screen, **I want the div to remain in the middle of page when the many is opened:**

[image]

**The Code:**

Please see the following JS Fiddle that shows the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/svjkv79j/

As stated I am using an of the shelf option for this menu but I have added my own styling for centering the text div, as shown:

```
         .centered {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

        <div class="centered">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <h1 class="page-header">Off-canvas Push Menu For Bootstrap 3</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque lobortis sem ut varius commodo. Nunc ultricies diam vel elit hendrerit, at mollis est elementum. </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

What styling is needed within the 'centered' div to stop it losing its style when the menu is opened? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give the `#page-content-wrapper { height: 100%; }`

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/svjkv79j/1/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, that seems to do the trick. Do you know why the transition speed is lost when closing the menu? It currently seems to 'snap' back to its original position unlike the smooth transition when it is opened.

Comment: @user1352057 Sorry for the delayed response. This answer was my last action before heading to bed. If nobody else solves it before.. I'll have a look tonight when I finish work.

Comment: many thanks for your reply again. That would be much appreciated!